# rows insert with checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I have table showing below:

```
<form method="post" action="insertassign_process.php">
             <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

        <?php
        echo"<thead>
                <tr><th>Tenant ID</th>
                    <th>Tenant ZIP</th>
                    <th>Process server ID</th>
                    <th>Process Server Name</th>
                    <th>Phone Nmuber</th>
                    <th>Select Process Server</th>
                    <th>Assign Proces Server</th>
                    </tr>   
              </thead>";
        include("connection.php");
        extract($_REQUEST);
            $SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM users where zip_codes='$zip'";
            $result_set =  mysql_query($SQLSELECT) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
            {
            ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" readonly name="t_id[]" value="<?php echo $t_id; ?>"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" readonly name="zip[]" value="<?php echo $zip; ?>"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" readonly name="pr_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> "></td>
                    <td><input type="text" readonly name="fullname[]" value="<?php echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name']; ?>"</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['phone_no']; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name[]" select="selected" value="<?php echo $row["t_id"]; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="assign_process" value="1"  /></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
        ?>

    </table><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button-loading" name="submit" data-loading-text="Loading...">Submit</button></form>
```

Now when I checked any check box (may be multi select) then selected data of that rows will be inserted another table. My query for inserting is:

```
        <?php
        session_start();
         include("connection.php");
        extract($_SESSION);
        extract($_POST);
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])==true)
        {
        $counter = count($_POST["name"]); /* COUNT THE PASSED ON NAME */

        for($x=0; $x<=$counter; $x++){

        if(!empty($_POST["name"][$x])){
       $CUSTOMER_NAME = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["t_id"][$x]);
      $PI_ADDRESS = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pr_id"][$x]);


       $qry="INSERT INTO select_process (id,tenant_select_id,process_select_id) VALUES ('','$CUSTOMER_NAME','$PI_ADDRESS')";
      mysql_query($qry);

      } /* END OF CHECKING THE CHECKBOX IF SELECTED */

      } /* END OF FOR LOOP */
      }
      else{

       echo"error";
       }
      ?>
```

But when I select multiple rows or any then it inserting only first row data.

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to insert empty value into id, I think your id field is primary key, so it can not be duplicate, I will suggest make your id key primary auto-increment, and write your code like this -

```
    <?php
    session_start();
     include("connection.php");
    extract($_SESSION);
    extract($_POST);
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])==true)
    {
    $counter = count($_POST["name"]); /* COUNT THE PASSED ON NAME */

    for($x=0; $x<=$counter; $x++){

    if(!empty($_POST["name"][$x])){
   $CUSTOMER_NAME = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["t_id"][$x]);
  $PI_ADDRESS = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pr_id"][$x]);


       $qry="INSERT INTO select_process (tenant_select_id,process_select_id) VALUES ('$CUSTOMER_NAME','$PI_ADDRESS')";

  mysql_query($qry);

  } /* END OF CHECKING THE CHECKBOX IF SELECTED */

  } /* END OF FOR LOOP */
  }
  else{

   echo"error";
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply......$qry="INSERT INTO select_process (id,tenant_select_id,process_select_id) VALUES ('','$CUSTOMER_NAME','$PI_ADDRESS')"  Here id is primary key and autoincement. But problem is same

Comment: If I select all rows then it is inserting correctly...But if less than all rows than only first row inserting.